# python manager managed list

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am using pythons multiprocessing module in some of my code. I have a controller class that controls a class and performs some action.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Manager

class dosomething(multiprocessing.Process):
        def __init__(self,managerList):
                self.mlist = managerList
                print self.mlist

        def run(self):
                self.mlist.append((4,5,6))

class doController:
        def __init__(self):
                mgr = Manager()
                self.mlist = mgr.list()
                self.mlist.append((1,2,3,4))
                t = dosomething(self.mlist)
                #t.daemon = True
                #t.start()

        def printer(self):
                return self.mlist


gd = doController()
print gd.printer()
```

Pring mlist in the init part of dosomething prints [(1, 2, 3, 4)] as expected but the list in the dosomething part does not work giving out IOError 11. Can anyone help if it's right or wrong?

Comment: "Does not work" is useless. What happens, what do you expect, if there is an error message what does it say (quote, not paraphrase), etc.

Comment: @delnan IOError 11 is what I get

Comment: *C*lass ; print without parenthesis ; multiprocess instead of multiprocessing ; *p*rocess . And finally, when all is cleared, it does nothing. How are we supposed to help with non-working code ? How are we supposed to reproduce your IOError ?

Comment: Updated code. I presumed my intentions was clear.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the `Process.__init__` is missing.

You don't necessarely need to create a Process subclass you could use functions:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def dosomething(mlist):
    mlist.append((4,5,6))

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    L = manager.list((1,2,3,4))

    p = Process(target=dosomething, args=(L,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I made some work around on my end and i am getting expected results. Thanks for your input.